# Check if Ember is in testing mode

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js

Does anyone know how to check if Ember is in testing mode?

I'm writing acceptance tests in Ember, and they are made difficult by some jQuery animations in the app, which run asynchronously outside of Ember's run loop and won't complete until after the test has already finished. Using wait helpers like `andThen(...)` doesn't wait for the animations to finish, because they are outside the run loop.

I don't really need to do acceptance testing of the animations, just of the DOM state after the animations finish, so to make things simple I'd like to disable the animations during acceptance testing. So I need to be able to check if Ember is in testing mode.

I am using Ember version 1.10.1

Comment: Are you using the ember-cli?

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, it's as simple as `Ember.testing`. This will be set to true in testing mode, but otherwise it's undefined, so I couldn't find it right away in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if (Ember.testing) { // don't animate }`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#property_testing

Comment: Is there a way to import **testing** from ember? 
or do i have to import **Ember** and later on do Ember.testing ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to test the environment:

```
import ENV from 'app/config/environment';

myFunc() {
  const isTesting = ENV.environment === ‘test’;
  if (isTesting) {...};
}
```

Checkout https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/issues/297#issuecomment-352408048.